# What is the meaning of the following line in the Jenniffer Lopez song "I'm into you"?

Tags: lyrics, music-video

There is a strange line (well actually the whole song is quite weird) in the Jennifer Lopez song [*I'm into you*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgLcQmlN2Xg):

> Sharpshooter you can call me the Zion

Does anyone know what this actually means? Is she claiming to be a Jewish assassin of sorts? Why on earth is she saying this?

The whole thing smells. Like watch the video clip for instance: there she dances in front of a south American pyramid. One can only resort to conspiracy theories as a means of explanation over how baffling this all is. Can anyone explain this without reference to the "Illumanati"?

Answer (score 1):

It could me a reference to the American Civil War, and the [**Battle of Mount Zion Church**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Mount_Zion_Church).
This battle was won by the Union who had on its side the [**Birge's Western Sharpshooters**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/66th_Illinois_Volunteer_Infantry_Regiment) who were very efficient companies of marksmen who probably helped to win this battle.

Note that these are not the only lyrics of the song that have a war vocabulary:

> [Verse 2]
> You got me and I could not defend it
> I tried but I had to surrender
>
> [Verse 3]
> Listen, now I'm strong baby I bring the fire on
> Sharpshooter, you can call me the Zion

*I'm not very familiar with conspiracy theories so I really can help here, but I did watch the music video and didn't find anything suspicious. Just the singer singing about her love feelings, dancing with various outfits, cuddling a man... it reminds me most of music video of pop music female singers.*

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the Illuminati, the Civil War, or the Zionist movement, I'm betting this is influenced by yet another repository of Old Testament inspired imagery, Rastafarianism-via-reggae.  The Rastafari religion conceptualizes itself as the fourth Abrahamic religion.  The four, in historical order, are Judaism, via Abraham's grandson Jacob/Israel, Christianity, via Israel's descendant David, Islam, via Abraham's son Ishmael (Jacob's half-uncle), and finally Rastafarianism, which reveres Emperor Haile Selassie I, who is said to have been a direct descendant of David, via his son Solomon's liaison with the (Ethiopian) Queen of Sheba.  Two major concepts in the religion are "Zion," representing the forces of good, and "Babylon," representing the forces of evil.

Rastafarian imagery is found in a lot of popular reggae music, including that of the prominent Rastafarian, and most famous international exponent of the style, [Bob Marley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=micvKa1rbxE).  Marley's music, as well as those of many of his contemporaries, also frequently referenced the [American cowboy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XiYUYcpsT4) and gangster movies popular in the Caribbean islands at the time.

Since this song has a light, but clear reggae influence, I'm guessing that the lyric is a tip of the hat, if not a particularly coherent one, to both the cowboy ("sharpshooter") and Rastafarian ("Zion") references in classic reggae, one written more with attention to the sound and the feel of the words then their actual meaning.